# Change in state not being rendered with object.map

Tags: reactjs, redux, rendering, reduce

The state of the redux store is changing as it should but cannot get the object.map function to re-render the new state. Getting the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Confirmed that data in actions.js is correct, confirmed that data in reducer.js is correct, confirmed state change in state.PrepInfos is correct.

Form:

```
class PrepInfos extends Component {
    render(){
        const{ PrepInfos } = this.props;

        return(
                <Form>
                    {PrepInfos.map(prepInfo => <PrepInfo key={prepInfo.id} id={prepInfo.id} type={prepInfo.type} quantity={prepInfo.quantity} description={prepInfo.description} />)}
                </Form>
        );
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    PrepInfos: state.recipeForm.PrepInfos.PrepInfos,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => bindActionCreators({

}, dispatch);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PrepInfos);
```

Actions:

```
export const H_CHANGE = 'H_CHANGE';

export function hChange(event) {

    const form = ({
        value: event.target.value,
        name: event.target.name,
        id: event.target.id,
    });

    return ({
        type: 'H_CHANGE',
        data: form,
    });
}
```

Reducer:

```
import { H_CHANGE } from './PrepInfo/actions';

const initialState = {
    PrepInfos: [{id:0, type:"makes", quantity:30, description:"slices"}, {id:1, type:"chill", quantity:15, description:"minutes"}],
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){

    const { type, data } = action;

    switch(type) {

        case H_CHANGE:

            return state.PrepInfos.map(prepInfo => {
                if (prepInfo.id == data.id) {
                    return {...prepInfo, [data.name]: data.value}
                };
                return prepInfo;
            });

        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Corrected Reducer:

```
return Object.assign({}, state, {
    PrepInfos: state.PrepInfos.map(prepInfo => {
        if (prepInfo.id == data.id) {
            return {...prepInfo, [data.name]: data.value}
            };
        return Object.assign({}, prepInfo, {});
    })
})
```

Expecting to re-render the new state, instead getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: how is `PrepInfos` getting into `props`? You are either missing a `connect` function or need to show more code

Comment: @EricHasselbring Just added the connection code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is caused by mutating state in the reducer

```
        // this is mutating the PrepInfos property in state
        return state.PrepInfos.map(prepInfo => {
            if (prepInfo.id == data.id) {
                return {...prepInfo, [data.name]: data.value}
            };
            return prepInfo;
        });

        // this is creating and returning a new obj for state and the PrepInfos key in state
        return {
          ...state,
          PrepInfos: state.PrepInfos.map(prepInfo => {
            if (prepInfo.id == data.id) {
                return {...prepInfo, [data.name]: data.value}
            };
            return prepInfo;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! I refactored the code a little bit to make it work but that was definitely the problem. I updated the question to include working code based on your solution